# PhpUnit when I use Mock Builder for Interface I get the correct class

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have the following class

```
namespace MyApp;

use MyApp\SomeInterface;

class MyClass
{
  public function __construct(SomeInterface $s)
  {
    //Some Logic here
  }

  //Another methods implemented There
}
```

The SomeInterface contains the following:

```
namespace MyApp

interface SomeInterface
{
  /**
  * @return SomeObject
  */
  public function someMethodToImpement();
}
```

And I want to create a mock over my phpunit Test Class:

```
namespace Tests\MyApp;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use MyApp\MyClass;
use MyApp\SomeInterface;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
   public function someTest()
   {

     $fakeClass=new class{
          public function myFunction($arg1,$arg2)
          {
            //Dummy logic to test if called
            return $arg1+$arg2;
          }
     };

     $mockInterface=$this->createMock(SomeInterface::class)
      ->method('someMethodToImpement')
      ->will($this->returnValue($fakeClass));

     $myActualObject=new MyClass($mockInterface);
   }
}
```

But Once I run it I get the error:

> Tests\MyApp\MyClassTest::someTest
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyApp\MyClass::__construct() must implement interface MyApp\SomeInterface, instance of PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\InvocationMocker given, called in /home/vagrant/code/tests/MyApp/MyClassTest.php on line

Do you know why that happens and how actually will create the mock Interface?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Instead of constructing the mock via

```
 $mockInterface=$this->createMock(SomeInterface::class)
      ->method('someMethodToImpement')->will($this->returnValue($fakeClass));
```

Split it into seperate lines:

```
 $mockInterface=$this->createMock(SomeInterface::class);
 $mockInterface->method('someMethodToImpement')->will($this->returnValue($fakeClass));
```

And will work like a charm.

Comment: thx, this works for me! imo, it worth mentioning in the answer (and i suggest you to append it) that the reason for this is that the `method()` and `will()` methods return invocation mocker instance while `createMock()` returns the mock itself, the very which actually has to be passed to the sut (sut - system under test)

Comment: How does this rearranging make any difference...?

Comment: The second time already stumbled here xD How to give another one Up vote?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. I fixed it by adding those interfaces as another `mock()` parameter

```
class Product implements PriceInterface, ProductDataInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Test:

```
// throws error
$product = Mockery::mock(Product::class);
// works fine
$product = Mockery::mock(Product::class, 'PriceInterface, ProductDataInterface');
```

[Link to documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#classes-abstracts-interfaces)